# Notation used in Router configuration diagrams

Tags: cisco, router, subnet, mpls

I was listening to an MPLS tutorial on youtube.[MPLS tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UjlRWyc_4k&list=PLQQoSBmrXmrzu9qjsNGBnevoE0-KBtyNt&index=75)
I came across this diagram.[image: MPLS diagram]

I am not that familiar with router configuration.My questions are as follows.

1) what does G1/0, G2/0, G3/0 and G4/0 shown in the diagram represent?

It would be great if someone could clarify this.

Comment: why the negative marking ? How does a person who is not familiar with the notation figure something like this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very likely to show the interfaces which are being used for the connection.

For example P4 and PE-1 are being connected together using the first Gigabit Port and P4 is connected to P5 using the second Port.

It's also good to note that naming conventions for interfaces are different for each manufacturer.

Comment: does it mean that `Port 1` on PE-1 is connected to `Port 0` on P4. `Port 2` on P4 connected to `Port 0` on P5 and so on?

Comment: No they all use the port before the slash. The 0 should show the network slot number on the device in this case (like said though, this changes from manufacturer to manufacturer). For example cisco usually use [something like this](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/3725-multiservice-access-router/62611-c2800-62611.html)